# how to identify params response logout azure ad

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

I have an azure ad application and login with saml and I logged out to my site, but it sends a request when the user leaves the azure ad for my site, how do I identify which user left? the response is very confusing and does not send any parameters.

it sends something like this to my website
SAMLRequest=lZJNi9swFEX%2fivFe9pOs%2bEM4poFQMExnoFO66GZ4luSMqS2legozP7%2bOwywCbaHbi67OPfBawmU%2bqwd%..

I've read the lib and I can't identify which user left azure ad

Comment: Hi @LorenzoCorrrea, did the suggested solution work for you? Do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot or else do accept it for helping other community members.

Answer (score 0):

•   You can surely **identify the user that left Azure AD, i.e., the user that logged out from Azure using the SAML protocol when leaving the site by decoding the SAML logout response in an online base64 decoder website**. The website on which you can decode the SAML logout response is given below. Also, ***do note that the SAML response is in bas64 encoded format due to which you are unable to read the information directly***: -

***https://www.base64decode.org/***

•   Also, to view and identify the SAML response in your browser for troubleshooting purposes, kindly follow the below steps according to the type of browser that you are using: -

a)  ***Google chrome:*** -

`Press F12 to start the developer console. Then, select the Network tab, and then select Preserve log. Reproduce the issue. Look for a SAML Post in the developer console pane. Select that row, and then view the Headers tab at the bottom. Look for the SAMLResponse attribute that contains the encoded request`.

b)  ***Mozilla Firefox:*** -

`Press F12 to start the developer console. In the upper right of the developer tools window, click options (the small gear icon). Under Common Preferences select Enable persistent logs. Select the Network tab. Reproduce the issue. Look for a POST SAML in the table. Select that row. In the Form Data window on the right, select the Params tab and find the SAMLResponse element`.

Similarly, follow the link below for more details on ***various kinds of browsers to identify the SAML response in the intercepted logout response***: -

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/troubleshoot_saml_view-saml-response.html

**Once you find the Base64-encoded SAML response element in your browser, copy it and paste it in the link given above in the first section and decode it for relevant information or paste the encoded SAML response in the command below in powershell and execute it**: -

```
 [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String("base64encodedtext"))
```